# Place of the time marker in a sentence

Tags: english-to-german, adverb

The questions are as follows:

- `I want ask about your approximate time of departure tommorow.`
- > Ich möchte nach Ihrer ungefähren Abfahrzeit fragen.

Where do I put the word 'morgen'?

Also:

- `I'm coming tommorow in the early afternoon.`
- > Ich komme morgen am frühen Nachmittag.

Is this correct?

Comment: A side note, if you want to ask someone a question then you shouldn't announce "I want to ask a question" but you should ask the question ;-) Why not just say "wann fahren Sie morgen ungefähr ab?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to your sentence, it would be 
"Ich möchte nach Ihrer ungefähren Abfahrzeit morgen fragen."

Depending on the situation you might also go for a less indirect way of asking: "Wann fahren Sie morgen ab?" or "Können Sie mir sagen, wann Sie morgen abfahren?" which sounds a bit more natural.

Comment: Können Sie mir sagen, wann Sie morgen abfahren is exactly what I was going for! The first suggestion I got was also useful, but I see it's a bit more 'official'.

Answer (score 4):

For the first question I would use this construct:

> Ich möchte nach Ihrer ungefähren Abfahrtszeit *für den morgigen Tag* fragen.

Your second suggestion is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Volker Landgraf: I would characterize '_für den morgigen Tag_' as "Verwaltungsdeutsch".

Comment: @RalfJoerres Da mein Vater vor seiner Pensionierung in der Tat Beamter war, kann ich nicht völlig ausschließen, dass es einzelne Formulierungen gibt, die für mich "normalen Sprachgebrauch" darstellen, von anderen aber vielleicht als "Verwaltungsdeutsch" empfunden werden. Verstanden wird es aber problemlos (was keineswegs bei allen Begriffen der Behördensprache der Fall ist)